# Submission on hold on arxiv

Tags: publications, arxiv

I have recently submitted a paper to arXiv, but the arXiv moderators put my paper in status "on hold", because they have to make a decision on the right classification for the paper.

To those who have experienced a similar situation, how long did it take before they made a decision and published the paper on the arXiv? I just want to have an idea of how long I will have to wait.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same experience with arxiv and it took only 1-2 days after they change my paper track. However, they mentioned it may take up to several days. The arxiv helps says

> On Hold
>
> Your submission was identified by arXiv administrators or moderators
>   as needing further attention.
>
> Submissions may be put on hold for a variety of reasons, ranging from
>   questions about proper classification, pending moderator approval,
>   presentation issues, copyrighted PDF, etc., to editorial concerns.
>   Most of these do not require any further input from the submitter and
>   will be dealt with in due course. arXiv urges submitters to be
>   patient. Due to the large volume of submissions, it may take several
>   days before a resolution is reached.
>
> Note that oversize submissions are automatically put on hold, and this
>   is one particular circumstance in which submitters should follow up
>   with arXiv administrators.
>
> Submissions in this status will not expire. Authors must not create a
>   new submission with the same content when a pending submission is on
>   hold.
>
> Please be sure to include the submission identifier of the form
>   submit/NNNNNNN when contacting arXiv administrators.

wait for few more days and send them an email. They are quick in response.

Comment: My article is onhold for more than 2 weeks now, and moderators don't reply at all.

Answer (score 6):

Sending an email to ask when to expect publication will trigger a standard response from arxiv.org that looks like this:

> Your submission is currently on hold pending a decision by our
>   volunteer moderators. The "hold" status merely indicates that one or
>   more of the moderators need additional time to consider your article.
>
> Due to the volume of mail arXiv receives, we are not able to provide
>   regular status updates. Upon resolution, your submission will be
>   deposited in arXiv, or we will contact you with further information.

Seems that long waiting times can occur particularly when volunteer moderators are in holidays. I received this answer several times during summer while my submission had "on hold" status for more than two weeks...

Comment: Do they notify when they are done?