# Arxiv puts submissions on hold for months, ignores email

Tags: publications, arxiv

What is the new fashion of arxiv.org to silently put a submission on hold for many months?

When I wrote to moderation email, the question was ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14511/22733

Answer (score 3):

Since lots of other people are getting their work published on arXiv right now, and [other answers show that arXiv is generally quite fast at handling holds and responding](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14511/22733), it is unlikely to be a general policy.  That leaves one of two basic possibilities:

1. You have fallen through the electronic cracks: some database fault or the like knocked your submission off of the moderators' queues and your email is going into their spam filters, so they have no idea that your submission is on hold.
2. Something about you and/or your submission is causing your submission to be continually deferred while the moderators take care of other business.

It certainly could be #1, in which case I would advise sending another email from another account, politely inquiring as to when you are likely to hear whether your submission is accepted or rejected.

Regarding #2: having no idea about your submission, I cannot speculate on whether it is the problem, but I suppose that it is possible that you have submitted something extremely borderline: hard for them to decide how to categorize and also unclear whether to reject.

If it was just about your submission, however, you probably would have received some response to your email.  If, on the other hand, you are being rude to the moderators, then it's possible you are not getting a response to your email for that reason.  Even in this case, it is unlikely to be an intentional decision (if that were the case, they would probably just reject you) and more likely a case of people just deferring the problem case to the bottom of their triage list.

The recommendation of how to proceed, however, is essentially the same as #1: send another *polite* email inquiring about when you are likely to hear whether your submission is accepted or rejected.  If you don't hear back in a few days, ask a colleague to send email on your behalf instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I understand that you have put several papers on arXiv. Usually, technical reports or drafts above-the-average get accepted. This one being turned down might have something to do with your *new fashion* of below-the-average writing.

Not every submission to arXiv is guaranteed to be accepted. Maybe you should revise your work and submit again.

Comment: unhelpful; it was not rejected but put on hold