# arXiv delays by putting paper on hold

Tags: arxiv

How common are arXiv delays? (putting a paper on hold status?). I have recently (yesterday) submitted my first paper on arXiv, it was supposed to show up a while ago, however the status of the paper was changed to on hold. How common is this? Also is it because I'm submitting my first paper on arXiv?

Also how many days does it generally takes for the paper's announcement after on hold?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submission on hold on arxiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/submission-on-hold-on-arxiv)