# Is there a way to know what the eventual URL of an arXiv paper will be before it is submitted?

Tags: arxiv

**Is there a way to know what the eventual URL of an arXiv paper will be before it is submitted?**

That is, the article exists as a draft in my arXiv.org account and has a 7-digit identifier of the form `submit/1234567`, but I have *not* yet pressed the submit button, so it doesn't yet have a permanent identifier in the form `1234.56789`.

---

Why do I want to do this? I am going to give a poster presentation about the same research at a conference in a few months. The conference has requested a digital copy of my poster by the end of the week. I would like to put a reference to the arXiv paper in my slides. However, I am waiting for a collaborator to sign off on the final draft of the paper before submitting to arXiv. Even if my collaborator signs off and I submit the paper to arXiv today, it may take until next week for the paper to make it through the arXiv referee process.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). The solution to your actual problem is to send them the slides without the arXiv reference, and when your paper gets posted to send an updated version and the organizers to replace the original, explaining that the only change is an added reference to the arXiv preprint. It’s very likely they’ll accommodate your request.

Comment: That would be my preference too, but unfortunately, these conference organizers are notoriously averse to such requests. The argument is that they need the final version ahead of the conference in order to compile the proceedings.

Comment: Hmm, I’d still make the request - it never hurts to ask. Point out the exact change you made, including line number in the source document, and the exact line substitution (to help the organizers swap in the change in case they already imported your submission into a larger proceedings doc file). E.g.: “In line 753, replace ‘Smith (2022)’ with ‘Smith (2022), see: arXiv:1224.5678’.” It may not work, but who knows, you might get lucky.

Comment: You may also add the preprint to ResearchGate and make the file private. RG will assign a permanent link to your entry and you may switch between public and private at any time.

Comment: ArXiv doesn’t have a referee process. Your paper will appear the next business day after you upload it.

Comment: Yeah, echoing what @Prahar said. arXiv does have a [moderation](https://arxiv.org/help/moderation) process, but that involves only the most basic checks to ensure that the paper isn't complete nonsense or otherwise wildly inappropriate, and it happens very quickly, within one business day. It's very different from the referee process (a.k.a. peer review) that a paper goes through when it's submitted to a journal.

Comment: @Prahar Papers *do* get kept for a few days on occasion ...

Comment: Ah, everything was better in the past - there was a time when the arxiv identifier was assigned right away when you started the submission process. (It should be noted that there were reasons they abandoned this.)

Comment: @user151413 when does that happen? I've uploaded several papers on arXiv and it has never happened to me so I'm curious under what circumstances do they hold papers.

Comment: @Prahar Not public, for obvious reasons. But you can see it from the fact that the submission time does not increase monotonically with the submission number, sometimes. (Then again, you shouldn't worry: Having a paper held is no reason to be proud of. Then again, there were even public fights about held papers ... )

Comment: @Prahar https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.5.029540/full/   There was quite some discussion at that time.

Comment: @user151413 Interesting!

Comment: @Prahar Also see https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/14511/17254

Comment: In case anyone is curious, I went ahead and submitted to arXiv and it looks like it will be announced in time for me to add its URL to my conference submission. I've only submitted to arXiv once, and it took 4 or 5 days to be announced, but that was probably because it was my first submission. My backup plan was to cite the URL for our public Github repo, which we use to post rolling updates to our paper and various conference slides. This aligns with what many suggested in the comments and answers.

Comment: @Max The schedule for when the next posting is is public (see https://arxiv.org/localtime),  and can be 3 days over the weekend, and more if e.g. Monday is a holiday.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since 2015, the identifier is of the form arXiv:YYMM.NNNNN. The YYMM part is simply the year and month, so it's easy to predict. The NNNNN part is a five digit sequence number within the month, which you won't know ahead of time. This is why arXiv [state](https://arxiv.org/help/availability)

> The final [arXiv identifier](https://arxiv.org/help/arxiv_identifier) cannot be assigned until the paper is announced, so please do not ask for it ahead of announcement. It is not possible to make exceptions, nor accelerate the announcement schedule regardless of your circumstance.

If you get the sign-off and submit today, there's a  reasonable chance it'll be posted in time. If that doesn't pan out, Dan Romik's advice is good.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it answers the question posed in the OP. I appreciate others' suggestions for my XY problem, but my question was truly about the mechanics of the arXiv service and not what alternatives are available to me in this situation.

Answer (score 29):

If you have a personal web site or domain, then instead of a link to the paper’s arXiv page, you can put in your slides a link to your publications page, or to a URL you can set up that either will serve up the paper’s file (once your coauthor approves the final version), or will serve up a basic HTML file with a redirect tag to another URL you can later customize to the posted preprint’s arXiv page.

(And if you don’t have a personal website, this situation is a good illustration of just one among many benefits of having one.)

Comment: If OP does not have a site, they may use a good URL shortener (URL shorteners are a terrible, terrible invention but I digress). Make sure you can edit the URL it points to afterward.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question:

No, there is no way to know the arxiv identifier before the submission is posted publicly on the arxiv.

That is, under normal circumstances, you will know your arxiv identifier at the next posting after your submission, i.e. earliest 6 hours after you submit.

(If the paper gets held back for any reason, the number will also only be assigned once the paper appears.)

Answer (score -1):

Another option for @dan-romik's URL redirection answer is to use smarturl.it. You provide the smartURL, and then can later change the redirection destination when the preprint goes up on arXiv.

This approach is also useful for double-blind conference submissions that require anonymous links to code/software at time of submission. You might create a Github repo that's tied to your personal identity, and linked from your website / social media. But you would create a pseudonymous Github account, a new repo (not a fork) that contains a copy of the same code, and then smartURL to this copy. Once your paper is accepted, you change the smartURL to your original Github repo.